# Raspberry Pi / ImageMagick: Screenshot via Crontab

Tags: imagemagick, cron

I'm trying to run a script via crontab on my Raspberry Pi.

I have created the script: `ScreenShot.sh`

The content of the file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0 && \
   import -window root -resize 20% /pathtofolder/screenshot.jpg
```

This works fine when I run it via SSH

```
/home/pi/ScreenShot.sh
```

I have made the script executable.

I then added it to cron via `sudo crontab -e`

```
*/1 * * * * /home/pi/ScreenShot.sh
```

I want the script to run ever 1 minute (I'll extend this later, but for testing purposes I have it at 1 minute).

For some reason the script does not run in crontab and does not take a screenshot.

I have noticed that if I run the script via `sudo`:

```
sudo /home/pi/ScreenShot.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
No protocol specified
import.im6: unable to open X server `:0' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/368.
```

I'm assuming when Crontab runs, it runs the script as Root, which might be causing the failure.

I enabled logging on crontab and if I view the log I see the following:

```
Nov  6 06:26:01 IRDigitalDisplay /USR/SBIN/CRON[12634]: (root) CMD (/home/pi/ScreenShot.sh)
Nov  6 06:26:02 IRDigitalDisplay /USR/SBIN/CRON[12633]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output
```

So I'm assuming something goes wrong. However it's not writing the error to the log, but rather trying to email it to me.....

My question is:

- How do I get my ImageMagick script to run in crontab, take a screen shot every X minutes, and save this into a predetermined folder?

Comment: Hi, I figured it out, you need to run the crontab job as Pi user: */5 * * * * sudo -u pi /home/pi/ScreenShot.sh

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the script to the "pi" users crontab, not root's. Start the crontab edior with this command as user "pi":

```sh
crontab -e
```

No `sudo` needed.

The crontab entry has to be:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/pi/ScreenShot.sh
```